# Slide on calculate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writting calculate now. And for example, when we change number width in left block on 750, in right block we would see 900, but when we change number of length in left block on 2000, in right block we would see also 2000. How to combine two sliders? This sliders are independent now.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mySlider").slider({
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 750,
    value: 750,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#total").val(ui.value);
    }
  });
  $("#total").val($("#mySlider").slider("value"));

  $("#rangeSlider").slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 3000,
    value: 3000,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#tot").val(ui.value);
    }
  });
  $("#tot").val($("#rangeSlider").slider("value"));

  $("#mySlider1").slider({
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 900,
    value: 900,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#total1").val(ui.value);
    }
  });
  $("#total1").val($("#mySlider1").slider("value"));

  $("#rangeSlider1").slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 3000,
    value: 3000,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#tot1").val(ui.value);
    }
  });
  $("#tot1").val($("#rangeSlider1").slider("value"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/hot-sneaks/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="before" style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 20px;">
  <p>
    <label for="tot"> Length:</label>
    <input type="text" id="tot" style="border:0; color:#fa4b2a; font-weight:bold;">
  </p>

  <div id="rangeSlider" style="height:250px; display: inline-block;"></div>

  <img src="123.png" alt="">

  <p>
    <label for="total">Width:</label>
    <input type="text" id="total" style="border:0; color:#fa4b2a; font-weight:bold;">
  </p>
  <div id="mySlider" style="width: 230px"></div>
</div>

<div class="after" style="display: inline-block;">
  <p>
    <label for="tot1"> Length:</label>
    <input type="text" id="tot1" style="border:0; color:#fa4b2a; font-weight:bold;">
  </p>

  <div id="rangeSlider1" style="height:250px; display: inline-block;"></div>

  <img src="123.png" alt="">

  <p>
    <label for="total1">Width:</label>
    <input type="text" id="total1" style="border:0; color:#fa4b2a; font-weight:bold;">
  </p>
  <div id="mySlider1" style="width: 230px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't work here. Most likely because of external resources (JQuery). If you can use [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net), [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/) or something else that can handle code snippets with external resources, it would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could update value of the slider that you need to sync with, using value setter `$( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "value", 10 );`

Here is the working code for your example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var $total = $("#total");
 var $total1 = $("#total1");
 var $tot = $("#tot");
 var $tot1 = $("#tot1");
 
        var mySlider = $( "#mySlider" ).slider({
          range: "min",
          min: 0,
          max: 750,
          value: 750,
          slide: function( event, ui ) { 
   mySlider1.slider( "option", "value", ui.value + 150 );
   $total.val(  ui.value );   
          },
    change: function(event, ui){
            $total.val(  ui.value );     
    } 
        });
        $total.val( mySlider.slider( "value" ) );
        
     var mySlider1 = $( "#mySlider1" ).slider({
          range: "min",
          min: 0,
          max: 900,
          value: 900,
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
   mySlider.slider( "option", "value", ui.value - 150 ); 
   $total1.val(  ui.value );   
          },
    change: function(event, ui){
            $total1.val(  ui.value );     
    } 
        });
        $total1.val( mySlider1.slider( "value" ) );
 
        var rangeSlider = $( "#rangeSlider" ).slider({
          orientation: "vertical",
          range: "min",
          min: 0,
          max: 3000,
          value: 3000,
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $tot.val( ui.value );
   rangeSlider1.slider("option","value", ui.value);  
          },
    change: function(event, ui){
   $tot.val( ui.value );  
    } 
        });
        $tot.val( rangeSlider.slider( "value" ) );
           
        var rangeSlider1 = $( "#rangeSlider1" ).slider({
          orientation: "vertical",
          range: "min",
          min: 0,
          max: 3000,
          value: 3000,
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $tot1.val( ui.value );
   rangeSlider.slider("option","value", ui.value);    
          },
    change: function(event, ui){
   $tot1.val( ui.value );  
    } 
        });
        $tot1.val( rangeSlider1.slider( "value" ) );
       function updateInput(e, slider){
          slider.slider( "option", "value", $(e.target).val() );
       }
       $total.on('keyup keydown',function(e){
      updateInput(e, mySlider);
       });
       $total1.on('keyup keydown',function(e){
     updateInput(e, mySlider1);
      });
       $tot.on('keyup keydown',function(e){
     updateInput(e, rangeSlider);
      });
      $tot1.on('keyup keydown',function(e){
    updateInput(e, rangeSlider1);
      });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/hot-sneaks/jquery-ui.css" /> 
  <title>jQuery UI : Slider with Minimum Range</title>
</head> 
<body>
<div class="before" style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 20px;">
  <p>
    <label for="tot"> Length:</label>
    <input type="text" id="tot" style="border:0; color:#fa4b2a; font-weight:bold;">
  </p>
   
  <div id="rangeSlider" style="height:250px; display: inline-block;"></div>

  <img src="123.png" alt="">

  <p>
    <label for="total">Width:</label>
    <input type="text" id="total" style="border:0; color:#fa4b2a; font-weight:bold;">
  </p>
  <div id="mySlider" style="width: 230px"></div>
</div>

<div class="after" style="display: inline-block;">
  <p>
    <label for="tot1"> Length:</label>
    <input type="text" id="tot1" style="border:0; color:#fa4b2a; font-weight:bold;">
  </p>
   
  <div id="rangeSlider1" style="height:250px; display: inline-block;"></div>

  <img src="123.png" alt="">

  <p>
    <label for="total1">Width:</label>
    <input type="text" id="total1" style="border:0; color:#fa4b2a; font-weight:bold;">
  </p>
  <div id="mySlider1" style="width: 230px"></div>
</div>
 R 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a jsbin of the above code https://jsbin.com/gicive/1/edit?js,output

Comment: Thank you very mutch. Excuse me, but do you know how to make sure that when I change the value in input, slide changed too?

Comment: Yes, sure that can be done. I will update my answer.

Comment: Updated my answer with your requested changes, please check.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if we change number in left block now, number in right block don't change.

Comment: Updated post and snippet link, please check.